# ngEChart not working with map

Tags: angularjs, angular-chart, echarts

I have ngEChart in my project.

When i load charts like pie, bar, funnel... it's working fine.

But when i try to load map chart like suggested in http://echarts.baidu.com/echarts2/doc/example/map4.html#-en

Chart is not loading & i am also not getting any error.

It's loading like this.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what am i missing here?